# NumberFormatException on Double.valueOf with comma decimal separator

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Double.valueOf with comma decimal separator throws NumberFormatException.
Java 1.7.0_67 and 1.8.0_25.

I also try to set DecimalFormatSymbols with "," as decimalSeparator.

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
assert "12,3".equals(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(12.3));
if (((DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance()).getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator() == ',')
    Double.valueOf("12,3");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse("12,3");
Double d = number.doubleValue();
System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Double.valueOf() is not Locale aware. It only understands numbers with dots as decimal places.

Luckily you can use the same NumberFormat instance for formatting *and* parsing which is Locale aware ....

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

System.out.println(format.format(12.3));   // ==> "12,3"
System.out.println(format.parse("12,3"));  // ==> 12.3
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Double.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) does not take the default locale into account. Note that the API documentation of the method explains exactly what format it expects. It also tells you this:

> To interpret localized string representations of a floating-point value, use subclasses of NumberFormat.

Use, for example, [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) instead to parse the string.

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
Double value = (Double) format.parse("12,3");
```